# Descriptive Stock Analysis using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to conduct a descriptive analysis of stock markets, I have introduced three CSV files which contain historical data for three different companies. What code should I use to enable the program to be able to output information such as mean, STD, for all three companies? I could do them individually at the moment. However, moving forward, I want to add more companies to my dataset.

Comment: This is a very vague question. You need to do a little more work and post some code that you have tried. We are here to troubleshoot, not write code for you.

Comment: company = [AMZN, GOOG, AAPL]

 for i in range(len(company)):
       company[i] = company[i].describe()
       print(company[i])

This is what I have so far, is there a more efficient method? Potentially using functions as opposed to 'for all'

Comment: So is this code working? I guess I'm not sure what the issue is? sorry